# recurse infinitely - Sytax - printStars(lines - 1);

Tags: java, recursion, data-structures

I have been given an assignment to have the output as follows: with in recursion.

```
****
***
**
*
**
***
****
```

My problem is I can't use any loops and must compile code strictly with one parameter of recursion with printStars(lines).

Here's my code:

```
public static void printStars(int lines) {
    if (lines==1) { //base case
        System.out.print("*");
    }else if (lines>1){ //recursive case
        printStars(lines-1);
        System.out.print("*");
```

However, the output is only printing:

```
Please enter a number: 4
****BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 2 seconds)
```

I can get this to work perfectly with a for loop however, do to this limitation of loops I need to have this work only in recursion. I have read methods to change a for loop to recursion but I'm still confused. Any help or ideas?

Thank you,

Comment: We will need to see the entire program.  We have no idea what parameter is being used to call `lines`, or for that matter whether `lines` is being called at all.

Answer (score 0):

In your current code, you call printStars(4). When this is called, the code recursively calls printStars(3), printStars(2), then printStars(1).

The first * comes from printStars(1). When that returns, the second * gets printed by printStars(2) after the recursive call. The third * is printed in printStars(3) after the recursive call, and the fourth * after the recursive call in printStars(4).

Think about the problem, and look at the shape of the output you are looking for. The pattern is 4,3,2,1,2,3,4 with an initial input of 4. This looks like you need to follow a pattern like:

```
public static void printStars(int lines) {
    if (lines ==1) {
        System.out.print("*");
    }
    else {
        // Do something before recursion
        // Recurse
        // Do something after recursion
    }
}
```

For your output, you should see this happening:

```
**** //printed when lines==4
***  //printed when lines==3
**   //printed when lines==2
*    //printed when lines==1
**   //printed when lines==2
***  //printed when lines==3
**** //printed when lines==4
```

Comment: I have thought long and hard about this problem. It appears that I'm slightly confused because, I have the recursive method doing a printStars(lines-1); However, I don't understand what I need to do to have all the stars put out correct one after the other if line==1 one star should be printed. However, if lines>=1 printStars(lines-1); should be executed: which should lead to 4, 3, 2, 1 correct??

Comment: Here's a hint, usually in problems like this, you would be allowed to use a loop within a recursive method. When your instructor says no loops, I'm pretty sure they are talking about not using a loop to solve the outer problem of printing each line. Your base case looks mostly good, and lines-1 looks good as an arg for the recursive call, you just need to work out how to print a new line, and how to repeat lines characters before and after recursion.